# Aws Cognito with @aws-amplify/ui-react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I had tried to implement aws Cognito with react app.
Everything was done according to documentation. Now when I tried to run, am getting the below error

*./node_modules/@aws-amplify/analytics/lib-esm/Providers/AWSKinesisFirehoseProvider.js

Module not found: Can't resolve '@aws-sdk/client-firehose' in 'C:\Users\Shehzab\test\ui\react-app\node_modules@aws-amplify\analytics\lib-esm\Providers'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the root of your project, try ...

`rm -fr node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`